# File uploaded with ftp_nb_put to FileZilla FTP server in PHP is corrupted

Tags: php, ftp

I'm trying to upload a file using an html form. The upload method is via FTP to a FileZilla server. I have successfully uploaded the file but it seem like only it's file extension and file name are the ones that get uploaded. The file is always corrupted and doesn't display it's file size when viewing the transferred file in windows explorer. This is my code. Please help.

```
include 'Connections/ftpgangconnect.php';
ini_set("upload_max_filesize", "250M");
ini_set("post_max_size", "250M");

if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $name = $_FILES['myfile'] ['name'];
    $size = $_FILES['myfile'] ['size'];
    $type = $_FILES['myfile'] ['type'];
    $temp = $_FILES['myfile'] ['tmp_name'];
    $error = $_FILES['myfile'] ['error'];
    $content = $_FILES['myfile']['content'];
    $temp = $_FILES['myfile'] ['tmp_name'];
    $name = $_FILES['myfile']['name'];
    $dest_file ="/".$name;

    // upload the file
    $upload = ftp_nb_put($ftp, $dest_file, $temp, FTP_BINARY);

    // check upload status
    if (!$upload) { 
        echo "FTP upload has failed!";
    } else {
        echo "Uploaded $name";
        ftp_close($ftp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the examples for the [`ftp_nb_put` function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-put.php). You should be calling the `ftp_nb_continue` in a loop, until the upload is finished:

```
// upload the file
$upload = ftp_nb_put($ftp, $dest_file, $temp, FTP_BINARY);

while ($upload == FTP_MOREDATA)
{
   // Continue uploading...
   $upload = ftp_nb_continue($ftp);
}
```

---

Though unless you need to do anything else in the loop, its pointless to use `ftp_nb_put`. Just use a simple [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) instead:

```
$upload = ftp_put($ftp, $dest_file, $temp, FTP_BINARY);
```