# Uploading file with ftp_nb_put to FTP server in PHP results in an empty destination file

Tags: php, ftp

Hello,
I'm doing a script to send files directly to a server by ftp protocol.
To do that, I use php ftp functions.

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect('XXXX.com', 21);

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, 'USER_XXXX', 'PWD_XXXX');
ftp_pasv($conn_id, true) or die("Cannot switch to passive mode");

if ((!$conn_id) || (!$login_result)) {
    die("Problem FTP connection !");
}

if (ftp_chdir($conn_id, 'SERVER_PATH')) {
    echo ftp_pwd($conn_id) . "\n";
} else {
    echo "Problem to change path\n";
}

ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $File, $localPath. $File, FTP_ASCII);


ftp_close($conn_id);
```

No error is announced, but the file that arrives on my server is empty.

I forgot to precise, my file to upload is a big xlsx file.

Comment: try turning error reporting `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: I did it and 0 errors appear

Comment: what does this line `ftp_nb_put($conn_id, $File, $localPath. $File, FTP_ASCII);` return?

Comment: Try `ftp_nb_put($conn_id,"fred",...)`

Comment: This line return 2.
'Try ftp_nb_put($conn_id,"fred",...)' That upload 'fred' with some content

Comment: And try sleeping for 10 seconds afterwards as it's non-blocking - just to test.

Comment: If your file is XLSX, you need to use `FTP_BINARY` not `FTP_ASCII`.

Comment: Thank you it works! Does that mean excel is working with a binary encoding ?

Comment: Excel files are binary files. Treating binary files as text file will corrupt them.

Comment: ASCII mode translates line-endings between Windows, Mac and Unix - some use linefeeds (Unix/Linux), some use carriage returns (old Macs), and some are horrible and inefficient and use both (Windows). ASCII mode should never be used for images, compressed/zip files, or anything other than pure text and even then it is probably preferable to convert outside of FTP with `dos2unix` and `unix2dos` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is just wrong. You use non-blocking [`ftp_nb_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-put.php), as if it were blocking.

If you want a simple code, you have to use [`ftp_put`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php).

If you really need a non-blocking code, you have to close the connection only after [`ftp_nb_continue`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-nb-continue.php) reports `FTP_FINISHED`. See [File uploaded with ftp_nb_put to FileZilla FTP server in PHP is corrupted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16294330/850848).

Otherwise your current code will just close the connection at a moment the upload hardly even started.

The "sleep", suggested in comments, is (as mentioned there) just for a test, you cannot reliably use it in a real code.

---

Your second problem is that you are uploading binary `.xlsx` files in a text/ascii mode (`FTP_ASCII`). You have to use a binary mode (`FTP_BINARY`). The text/ascii mode will corrupt binary files. So even, if the upload finishes, the file will be corrupted.

---

This will work:

```
ftp_put($conn_id, $File, $localPath.$File, FTP_BINARY);
```